# built-in standard template engine for smtp

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

my app has a feature to send dynamic invitation messages from customer(company) email to its users

I'm using nodejs with nodemailer my app basically store a smtp string for every customer(company)

every customer(company) has its own custom body in the email with its custom parameters so I'm using pug template engine where parameters are binded to the html and sent as email body

but what if I want to send 100 emails
if I send them one by one this will keep my app in a long loop. Is SMTP has a standard rendering engine where I can just send the array of objects and its done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no way around this just kept sending the emails to the customer SMTP separately. it helps in nodejs non-blocking approach. I also made a small benchmarker so I can rate the SMTP server before integrating with it.
https://github.com/hadyrashwan/smtp-benchmarker